# how to access multidimensional array at different level in php

Tags: php

I am unable to access title and description in php. Though I have slight clue that we will have to use foreach loop at different level but being a beginner I have no idea how to fetch key and values in foreach loop.

Please run the following lines in .php and see the result.

```
<?php

$url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&apiKey=SECRET_KEY";

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
foreach ($response as $key => $value) { 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you can access the values using foreach.
Just change `$response` to `$response['articles']` because all data is present in the articles array of $response variable. You can iterate through articles array using foreach as below to access each element.

```
foreach ($response['articles'] as $key => $value) { 
    echo $value['title']; // to access title
    echo $value['description']; // to access description
}
```

Reference: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, when I write

foreach ($response['articles'] as $key => $value) { 
    echo $value['title'];

an error occurs, it says.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Xamp\htdocs\Muhammad\newsapi.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your timely response, I tried this way and it worked.

```
foreach ($response['articles'] as $key => $articles)
{ 
    echo $articles['source']['id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $articles['description'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $articles['author'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Published at"."<br>".$articles['publishedAt'];

    echo "<br><br><br><br>";
```